# Kibana - Show visualizations of top 5 (line date histogram)

Tags: elasticsearch, filtering, kibana, kibana-7

I'm using kibana's line visualization to get a graph for multiple series over time.

I want to filter the graph to get the 5 worst series (by the last values).

I've tried to add size = 5 at Split Series but I got the top 5 in each date (I need to filter by the last date only).

Excel's graph
[image]

kibana's graph
[image]

kibana's info:

[image]

Thanks!